# How do I select the first item independent of the number of dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional `numpy.array` called `my_imgs`. I want to store the array as an image. The dimensions of the array are not constant. At the moment I have four or five dimensions; later I will add more dimensions. For all diemensions from the 4th diemension on, I always want to select the first element. Is there a function to always select the first element regardless of the number of dimensions?

At the moment I have a separate if statement for each dimension.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# shape (number, row, col, channel, stack, ...)
my_imgs = '' # Multidimensional image array



fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.axis('off')

    if len(my_imgs.shape) == 4:
        ax.imshow(my_imgs[i, :, :, 0], cmap='gray_r')
    elif len(my_imgs.shape) == 5:
        ax.imshow(my_imgs[i, :, :, 0, 0], cmap='gray_r')
    elif len(my_imgs.shape) == 6:
        ax.imshow(my_imgs[i, :, :, 0, 0, 0], cmap='gray_r')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slice that numpy uses to specify 'the entire dimension', `:`, is equal to `slice(None)`.

This means you can do

```
import numpy as np


arr_5d = np.zeros((10, ) * 5)
arr_6d = np.zeros((10, ) * 6)


def my_slicer(arr, i=0):
    indexer = (i, slice(None), slice(None)) + (0,) * (len(arr.shape)-3)
    return arr[indexer]


# will print (10, 10) (10, 10)
print(
    my_slicer(arr_5d, i=2).shape,
    my_slicer(arr_6d, i=-3).shape,
)
```